# Error 403 Forbidden Cakephp AJAX

Tags: ajax, cakephp

Estoy intentando hacer una petición Ajax y me salta el error 403 forbidden por lo que he estado investigando es un problema de acceso al cual yo he puesto.

```
 function EnviarInformacion(accion,objEvento){
    var fecha = $('txtFecha').val();
    var titulo = $('#txtTitulo').val();
    var hora = $('#txtHora').val();
    var color =$('#txtColor').val();

  $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:'<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' =>'CalendarioPlantillas', 'action' => 'agregar')); ?>',
      dataType: "json",
      data:{
        fecha:fecha,
        titulo:titulo,
        hora:hora,
        color:color
      },
      beforeSend: function(xhr) 
      {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      },
      succes(msg){
        calendar.rerenderEvents()
          $("#ModalEventos").modal('toggle');
          $.notify('<?= __("Evento almacenado correctamente") ?>','success');
      },
      error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorMessage){
        alert("ERROR" + errorMessage + textStatus + xhr);
      }
  });
```

}

Y para permitir el uso de mi action agregar añadí el siguiente código.

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow(['agregar','delete']);
}
```

Comment: Fíjate que pusiste un . (punto) en el array del Allow. Debería ser , (coma)...

Comment: no tengo una coma, pero gracias por avisar, voy a corregir mi pregunta